# How to trigger MinGW to link "msvcr100.dll" instead of the "msvcr.dll" within the "libstdc++.dll" and "libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll"`?

Tags: windows-xp, mingw, msvcrt, libstdc++, setlocale

Platform: Windows XP;
MingGW with (gcc v.4.7.2)

As stated in the topic, how can I achive this?

Why? I determine a crash of my multi-threaded application on Windowx XP, in case I compile the application with MinGW. According to the backtrace, the application crashes in the "setlocale" function, which is builtin in the "msvcrt.dll".

I've tried to compile my application with Visual Studio 2010 and I determined no such a crash, as the dependency walker revealed, that the "msvcr100.dll" is linked, and maybe contains a more robust version of the "setlocale" function.

Here the backtrace:

```
ABoostLog.exe caused an Access Violation at location 77c03509 in module msvcrt.dll Reading from location 00000000.

Registers:
eax=00cdfb88 ebx=003d6afc ecx=003d6d24 edx=003d6d24 esi=00000758 edi=00000000
eip=7c91eb94 esp=00cdfb4c ebp=00cdfbb0 iopl=0 nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=001b ss=0023 ds=0023 es=0023 fs=003b gs=0000 efl=00000246

Call stack:
7C91EB94 ntdll.dll:7C91EB94 KiFastSystemCallRet
7C802532 kernel32.dll:7C802532 WaitForSingleObject
0041E33D WithThread.exe:0041E33D
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Registers:
eax=77c2f94c ebx=77c2f94c ecx=00000000 edx=77c2f798 esi=77c2f79a edi=ffffffff
eip=77c03509 esp=0022f520 ebp=0022f534 iopl=0 nv up ei ng nz ac po cy
cs=001b ss=0023 ds=0023 es=0023 fs=003b gs=0000 efl=00000297

Call stack:
77C03509 msvcrt.dll:77C03509 unguarded_readlc_active_add_func
77C03C1B msvcrt.dll:77C03C1B
unguarded_readlc_active_add_func
77C03C60 msvcrt.dll:77C03C60 setlocale
6FC671D1 libstdc++-6.dll:6FC671D1 std::__timepunct::_M_put
6FC7A63C libstdc++-6.dll:6FC7A63C std::time_put > >::do_put
6FC7A4CA libstdc++-6.dll:6FC7A4CA std::time_put > >::put
004EE047 ABoostLog.exe:004EE047
```

So my question is, how to trigger MinGW to link against "msvcr100.dll" within the "libstdc++.dll" and "libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll".

I've already adapted my spec-file to:

> *libgcc: %{mthreads:-lmingwthrd} -lmingw32    %{shared-libgcc:-lgcc_s} %{!shared-libgcc:-lgcc_eh} -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcr100

But this doesn't help, as the mentioned dll is still linked within the dll's stated. Just take a look to the embedded picture:

[image]

Thanks so far!

Br

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is, how to trigger MinGW to link against "msvcr100.dll"
>   within the "libstdc++.dll" and "libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll"

Those libs are supplied and built by MinGW, they are not built as part of your own application build. So you would need to first build those two libs yourself from source to get them to link to msvcr100.dll

But what you should really be doing is linking your application statically to these two libs and eliminating the dll dependencies. For example, in your configure.ac you could use:

```
CFLAGS="$CFLAGS --static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++"
LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS --static"
```

I still doubt that your particular crash is caused by this. Many dlls depend on msvcrt; just expand your WS2_32.dll for example.

By the way, your custom spec should use `-lmoldname100`